# Render multiple html files and views and show it in single html file Django

Tags: django, django-templates, jinja2

Below shown are my files

`index.html`

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade modal{{link.id}}" id="createmodal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Create Contact</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <form method='POST'>
          {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="modal-body">
          {{form.as_p}}
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-delete" data-sid="{{link.id}}" >Create Contact</button>
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary save-btn">
        </div>
      </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

`new_contact.html`

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade modal{{link.id}}" id="createmodal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Create Contact</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <form method='POST'>
          {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="modal-body">
          {{form.as_p}}
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-delete" data-sid="{{link.id}}" >Create Contact</button>
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary save-btn">
        </div>
      </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

`views.py`

```py
def new_contact(request):
    data = Contact.objects.all()
    form = CreateContactForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Link edited successfully.')
    else:
        messages.error(request, form.errors)

    return render(request,'app/editModal.html', context={'form':form,'data':data})
```

```py
def index(request):
    data = Contact.objects.all()
    return render(request,'app/editModal.html', context={'form':form})
```

I want to render `new_contact.html` file in `index.html` file. I have already used include tag but it doesn't work for my requirement. include tag includes that html file into the index file but does not render the `new_contact` function.
**I want to render the `new_contact.html` file with `new_contact` function into `index.html` file.**

Thank you

Comment: Can you tell me how did you used include template tag ?

Comment: Also it seems both the form in the templates are redundant similiar views so why not combine the two ?

Comment: In which view function do you use the `index.html` template? Where is the variable `link` you use in the templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An important rule: `Don't repeat yourself!`. Or maybe you have pasted same html code by mistake?

**You can't and shouldn't mix different views**. Also, you cannot have two `forms` with the same name because the first one will be overwritten by the second one.